# Variable generic assignment in generate loop

Tags: vhdl

What I want to do doesn't seem particularly complex, but I can't think of a simple way to do it in VHDL.

I have a component with a generic parameter called `FOO`. I would like to generate 16 of these components and for the first 8 instances I want `FOO` to be set to `0` and the other 8 instances I want `FOO` to be set to `4096`.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like this:

```
generate_loop: for I in 0 to 15 generate
begin
  comp_inst: my_component
  generic map
  (
    FOO => 0 when I < 8 else 4096
  )
  port map
  (
  ...
  );
end generate;
```

This is of course not valid VHDL, but that captures the idea of what I'd like to do.

So my question is: is there a way to implement this in a single generate loop (i.e. without having to have 2 separate generate loops with different indices), and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: You can always declare a function describing the mapping you want, and call it in the generate statement

Comment: Or use the fact that integer values truncate: `FOO => 4096*(I/8)`

Comment: JHBonarius' method uses the base type of the range in the for generate loop (universal integer) and integer division. Additionally you could use if generate statement(s)* nested inside the for generate statement. (* prior to -2008 you'd need two, in -2008 there's are elsif/else alternatives available for an if generate statement). The if generate statements can handle more than one case.

Comment: @JHBonarius I thought of trying something like that but didn't know how to about doing it. That seems like the right solution for my particular case. Will you make an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user1155120 mentions in the comments, the base type of a for-loop is a universal integer. The fractional part of an integer division will be truncated. You can use this fact to realize your specific system, as

- for 0<=i<8, i/8=0
- for 8<=i<15, i/8=1

Thus the code could be

```
generate_loop: for I in 0 to 15 generate
begin
    comp_inst: entity work.my_component
        generic map (FOO => 4096 * (I/8))
        port map (
            ...
            );
end generate;
```

Alternatively, especially useful for more complex situations, you could do what Brian Drummond suggested: write a function

```
architecture arch of ent is
    function gen_FOO(I : natural) return natural is begin
        if I<8 then
            return 0;
        else
            return 4096;
        end if;
    end function;
begin
    generate_loop: for I in 0 to 15 generate
    begin
        comp_inst: entity work.my_component
            generic map (FOO => gen_FOO(I))
            port map (
                ...
                );
    end generate;
```